# Onclick image not changing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to click an image and change IMAGE to another image in my folder but that didn't work so I settled for a button but that's not doing what I want either. When I use the onclick the image does not change. It's for a project and embedded JS code will not be accepted so we have to put it into a separate file.

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <br>
        <div class="logo">
        <img src="logo.png" width="270" height="240">
        </div>
        <script src="functions.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shirt.css">

    </head>
    <body>
    <br>
    <div class="scrollmenu">
    <nav class="navbar">
          <a href="shirt.html">Home</a>
          <a href="Shop.html">Shop</a>
          <a href="discounts.html">Discounts</a>
          <a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a>
    </div>
    </nav>
    </header>

    <br>
    <div class="t1">
    <h2 class="heading">CUSTOMISE YOUR SHIRT..</h2>
    <div class="customT1">
    <img id="IMAGE" src="t1.png" width="540" height="540"/><p>&euro;10.00</p>
    <p>Select one of the designs from below..</p>
    <img src="drift.png" width="140" height="140" border="2";/>
    <img src="clutch.png" width="140" height="140" border="2"/>
    <img src="jdm.png" width="130" height="140" border="2"/>
    <img src="twosik.png" width="140" height="140" border="2"/>
    </br>
    <button class="button" type="button" onclick= "alert();">USE</button>
</div>



</div>

    <br>
    <footer>
    <p>@Liam Chambers 2016</p>
    </footer>
</body> 

    enter code here

</html>
```

JS:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">

    function alert(){
    alert("hi");
    document.getElementById("IMAGE").src = "t1drift.png";
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console? What error message are you getting? Might I also suggest writing it in jQuery instead of vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: The problem is your choice of function name. `alert()` is already used. Try thinking of a different function name. I would also recommend only displaying the relevant source code when seeking help on StackOverFlow.

Comment: @MCMXCII why on earth would adding a huge dependency such as jQuery be a benefit for such a simple operation as this?!

Comment: By using alert() as function name you are overriding the default browser `alert()` function. Your call to alert ends up in error (Max call Stack Size Exceeded, because `alert()` keeps calling itself)

Comment: Link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764961/change-an-image-with-onclick

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('IMAGE').src='t1drift.png'">USE</button>
```

Comment: Introducing inline js code is bad practise.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941483/onclick-vs-event-handler

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use jquery, it will be an simple solution to this

```
<script>
$(function(){
   function alert(){
      $("#IMAGE").attr('src','t1drift.png');
   }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Adding a large library such as jQuery for such a simple operation as this is completely unnecessary.

Comment: i agree that. but in future if he wants to do any other higher operations means it will be useful at that moment

Answer (score 0):

A question already answered there [Change image when clicking button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609387/change-image-when-clicking-button)

Follow this link to get an idea. You can not use use built-in JS function for your function name. You should use unique function name.

Comment: Please don't post answers that consist of links.  If the links break in the future the answer becomes obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:-

```
document["imgName"].src="../newImgSrc.jpg";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("imgName").src="../newImgSrc.jpg";
```