# How do I change the color of the green parakeet picture to a blue parakeet picture in HTML using a function?

Tags: html, css, image, function, html-helper

I'm doing an HTML assignment for a class at university and I was stuck on a problem asking me to create a button with the label “Change color!”. When the button is pressed, a script will execute causing the “green_parakeet.jpg” image to be replaced with “blue_parakeet.jpg”.

When I emailed the professor, she said for me to add `onclick="statement"` property, e.g. you can call a function here as shown in the example from the LX12 document `<button onclick="f(x);">`. Then you can write a script language to set up the function in a way that img tag should change src property value to a new one.

Here's my HTML code so far

```
<img src = "green_parakeet.jpg">
<button> Change Color! </button>
```

I can't figure out what to do next.

Comment: You need either JavaScrpt / jQuery.  There are a ton of tutorials out there to show you how to trigger some action when you click a button.  There are also other questions on this site that will help you.  Start with a search like  "how to change an image on button click in javascript"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change image when clicking button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609387/change-image-when-clicking-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created this code according to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_events).

```
<script>
function change() {
document.getElementById("image").src = 'blue_parakeet.jpg';
 }
 </script>
 <img id="image" src = "green_parakeet.jpg">
<button onclick="change()"> Change Color! </button>
```

**edit:** The code below will remove the onclick.

```
<script>
function change() {
document.getElementById("image").src = 'blue_parakeet.jpg';
document.getElementById('button').removeAttribute("onclick");
}
</script>
<img id="image" src="green_parakeet.jpg">
<button id="button" onclick="change()"> Change Color! </button>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it also says that any additional button presses should not do anything to the image, just the first button press.

Comment: Then add id="button" to the button and add this inside the function.

`document.getElementById('button').removeAttribute("onclick");` It will remove the onclick from the button and button will do nothing.

Comment: So the whole thing from start to finish is like this?<script>
function change() {
document.getElementById("image").src = 'blue_parakeet.jpg';
 }
 </script>
 <img id="image" src = "green_parakeet.jpg">
<button onclick="change(document.getElementById('button').removeAttribute("onclick"))" id="button"> Change Color! </button>**

Comment: I mean ignore the two astericks before and after the code.

Comment: `<script>
function change() {
    document.getElementById('button').removeAttribute("onclick");
document.getElementById("image").src = 'blue_parakeet.jpg';

 }
 </script>
 <img id="image" src="green_parakeet.jpg">
<button id="button" onclick="change()"> Change Color! </button>`